# Interpretation of output of nvidia-smi and lspci | grep -i nvidia

Tags: nvidia, graphics-processing-unit, gpu, graphics

I am very new to GPU servers. I submitted a slurm job and then checked "nvidia-smi". I got the following outputs.

[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R63UO.png)

Then, I ran "lspci | grep -i nvidia" where I got this output.

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102GL [RTX A5000] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
25:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102GL [RTX A5000] (rev a1)
25:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
41:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102GL [RTX A5000] (rev a1)
41:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
61:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102GL [RTX A5000] (rev a1)
61:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
81:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102GL [RTX A5000] (rev a1)
81:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
a1:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102GL [RTX A5000] (rev a1)
a1:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
c1:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102GL [RTX A5000] (rev a1)
c1:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
e1:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102GL [RTX A5000] (rev a1)
e1:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Please help me to understand the details of these outputs.